# Can't get spring boot working with letsencrypt keystore

Tags: java, spring-boot, lets-encrypt

This is how I created my keystore:

```
sudo openssl pkcs12 -export -in /etc/letsencrypt/live/mypage/fullchain.pem -inkey /etc/letsencrypt/live/mypage/privkey.pem -out /opt/mypage/mypage.p12 -name mypage -CAfile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mypage/chain.pem -caname root -passout pass:changeit
```

This is my spring configuration:

```
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.port=443
server.ssl.key-store=/opt/mypage/mypage.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password=changeit
server.ssl.keyStoreType=PKCS12
server.ssl.keyAlias=mypage
```

These are the details of my keystore:

```
keytool -list -keystore mypage.p12

Keystore type: PKCS12
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

mypage, Mar 7, 2023, PrivateKeyEntry, 
Certificate fingerprint (SHA-256): ...
```

No matter what I do I get this exception:

`Caused by: java.io.IOException: Alias name [mypage] does not identify a key entry`

I spent hours on this and can't find what I'm missing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `server.ssl.key-store-type` and `server.ssl.key-alias`

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but with Spring Boot 2.7.0 and later you can use the properties `server.ssl.certificate`, `server.ssl.certificate-private-key`, `server.ssl.trust-certificate`, and `server.ssl.trust-certificate-private-key` to use the PEM certificates from LetsEncrypt directly without having to convert them to PKCS12 files.